# Method(s) for securing embedded images delivered to authenticated users?

Tags: image, security, authentication

As part of an application my users can create documents with embedded images/files/text etc. Viewing and editing this content requires the user to log in. At the moment the images and files though are delivered as permanent links so if those links are shared any non-authenticated user can access them forever.

I would like to make these files secure. My initial thought was to use the login token and user's id to check if they have access and only deliver the files if they do. But then I started working on it and it seems the most practical solution would involve generating a link that will expire at some point in the future. This doesn't remove the exposure to unauthenticated access but maybe reduces it enough.

The questions that come to mind are:

- Is there a common approach or a few options on how this should be implemented?

  - I've seen returning urls with expiration periods used
  - Google docs seems to do something more sophisticated for it's embedded images but I can't tell what
  - Others?
- Basic design points?
- Pros/Cons of each?

Comment: Your initial approach is the right idea.  What web application framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Meteor and its corresponding accounts package which makes authentication on the server-side a bit more complicated but I've found enough information on that bit that I think I can work through it. I've heard of generating expiring links/urls that point to files but am not sure if A) that would work well for embedded images and B) if there is a better way to handle this in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it reduces the authenticated access to a fixed time but theoretically it provides un-authenticated access. So a security professional will claim it has no authentication. This kind of timed expiry link is usually used to safeguard against one time un-authenticated access like password reset(along with an expiring token independent from the time).

What is your goal? From whom are you trying to protect the data? Is the users who already have access to files and you want to limit providing an expiry time?  From the question, you need to secure the access to the files/documents which has text and embedded images in it from everyone. You are right about the timed expiry design. It will not guarantee you authentication and integrity of the document and if it is over non-secure HTTP it will not even provide you integrity of the document from a potential adversary.

you can use cookies(secure cookie) over HTTPS. As long as the user has the non-expired cookie, allow access to the files/documents. The cookie approach needs distributed cookie management if you to host the solution in multiple boxes with a reverse proxy in-front. Though cross-site scripting is a threat but still most of major web application providers are using cookie based solutions. Please note, cookie breaks the [REST](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/11/20/basic-and-digest-authentication-for-a-restful-service-with-spring-security-3-1/) nature of the web-application.

Another approach (similar to cookie) is to generate authenticated tokens tied to user/documents which has access for N number of attempts for a time period set while generating the token. This method has to be used over HTTPS to avoid un-wanted listeners.

An always changing link is very costly to manage and not scalable over time because it is too much state to manage and application crash makes it even more costly. Re-directing to authentication is a safe bet for you provided you have already cookie management in place or you have one application instance to take care of.

Or you can you [HTTP digest authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) provided that your framework supports it so that you do not have to worry about the cookie-hell. Please note that you may need to write up some client-side java script based on your use case.

Comment: For third party users Google uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth to handle authentication. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth . All requests to the Google Drive / Docs are authenticated using tokens send with the request. I do not know their implementation or anything more in detail.

Comment: To add to this, you could upload the files to Amazon S3 since it's physical files and limit access to the files with the application. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

Comment: As it happens I am doing this already, albeit indirectly with filepicker.io... Filepicker includes the same HMAC signing options which I do use as well. My biggest question is in ways to approach this. As I've been reading it seems like sending a single use nonce is something that can work well to avoid risk of replay attacks but of course that adds to the overhead of the whole system. I think signing the files and having a small time expiration is the appropriate solution.